# Smooth transitions between loading and not loading

Tags: reactjs

I've seen on a few websites a really nice design that I would like to replicate.

When something is loading, e.g. payment details are being submitted, an animation is displayed and then when this the loading is finished, the animation seamlessly moves into another state, without any flickering.

How do I implement something like this? The traditional loading spinner just hides when loading is completed and even a fade just makes it a bit less janky. I guess what I would like is when loading is completed, you transition into something else with the same component?

Answer (score 0):

the problem calls `layout shift`...

when some element disappears from dom. other elements positions change and every thing do kind of shift! and yes its bad practice for ui/ux experience to have layout shift in your app.

for prevent layout shifts on animations using the CSS transform property can help reduce the chances of layout shifts occurring without any prior user input.
also you can use library for animations like framer or motion etc.
**when you change the element existence on dom always think about how to keep the empty place with other elements** try to reserve space beffore element exists inside parent elmenet.